# Problemas al tratar de cambiarle el nombre a una foto que se encuentra en un directorio

Tags: laravel

Quiero poder cambiar el nombre de una archivo desde un dato que envío por un formulario, el archivo se encuentra dentro del directorio `/public` de mi proyecto, y este es el código que tengo:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $photo = Photo::find($id);

    $oldFileName = $photo->filename;
    $extension = $photo->extension;
    $newFileName = $request->input('filename');

    if (strcmp($oldFileName, $newFileName) !== 0) { 

        Photo::move(public_path('image/').$oldFileName.$extension,public_path('image/').$newFileName.$extension);
    }

    $photo->fill($request->all())->save(); 

    return redirect()->route('index')->with('message', $photo->year);
}
```

Y este el error:

> BadMethodCallException 
>   Call to undefined method App\Photo::move()

Así están configurados los discos de Storage en **/config/filesystems.php**

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
    ],

],
```

Comment: El error es porque `Photo` es una clase que extiende de la clase `Model`, y `move()` es un método de la clase `Storage`. Para usar `move()`, debes hacerlo de esta manera: `Storage::move('old/file.jpg', 'new/file.jpg');`. Doc: [Storage: Copying & Moving Files](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#storing-files)

Comment: Gracias, eso lo resuelve pero ahora me da este error:  `League \ Flysystem \ FileNotFoundException
File not found at path: C:/xampp/htdocs/multiples/public/image/04.jpg` y si está bien la ruta y existe el archivo, porque la pegué en la pestaña de rutas de una carpeta y abrió la imagen

Comment: Eso posiblemente porque el disco por defecto apunta a el directorio `/storage/app/`. Muéstranos cómo tienes configurados los discos en el archivo `/config/filesystems.php` bajo el índice `'disks'` verás algo como [esto](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5639581ea56ecd556cdf6e6edc37ce5795740fd7/config/filesystems.php#L44).

Comment: Agregado a la pregunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error es porque `Photo` es una clase que extiende de la clase `Model`, y `move()` es un método de la clase `Storage`.

Como estás manipulando archivos en el directorio `/public/`, en vez del directorio `/storage/app/`, creo que lo más limpio aquí sería crear un disco para ese directorio. Puedes agregar un disco en el archivo `/config/filesystems.php` bajo el índice `'disks'` con un array como el siguiente:

```
'disks' => [
    // tus otros discos déjalos tal cuál están, y agrega este
    'image' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path('image'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/image',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
],
```

Luego podrás usar ese disco para manipular archivos en el directorio `/public/image/` de esta manera: `Storage::disk('image')->algunMetodo()`.

Para el caso de renombrar un archivo sería así:

```
Storage::disk('image')->move($oldFileName.$extension, $newFileName.$extension);
```

También, siempre tienes la posibilidad de chequear que el archivo exista antes de intentar manipularlo:

```
if( Storage::disk('image')->exists($oldFileName.$extension) )
    Storage::disk('image')->move($oldFileName.$extension, $newFileName.$extension);
```

Comment: Me funcionó bien, muchas gracias. Yo podría utilizar el disco public `Storage::disk('public')` y luego agregar a la ruta `/image/`? para no tener que crear otro disco?

Comment: No sé si entiendo bien lo que preguntas... Pero si miras en la configuración, el disco `'public'` apunta al directorio `/storage/app/public/` (`'root' => storage_path('app/public')`), o sea  que lo puedes usar para archivos y subdirectorios que estén ubicados ahí. De todas formas te sugiero que no modifiques los discos que trae laravel por defecto, sino que crees tu disco personalizado si los otros no te sirven.

Comment: Si lo que me preguntas es si puedes usar el disco `'public'` para guardar archivos que también estén disponibles en el directorio `/public/` la respuesta es **Sí, si creas un link simbólico de `public/storage` a `storage/app/public`, los archivos estarán disponibles bajo `/public/storage/...`**.

Comment: Me refería a si en vez de crear el disco `image`, usar directamente `Storage::disk('public')` pero agregar image a la ruta, `Storage::disk('public/image')` para no crear un disco nuevo ya que existe el disco `publi`c en la lista y es el que uso.

Comment: Ahh.. ok. No así realmente, al método `disk()` sólo puedes pasale el nombre de un disco (los que están en filesystems.php), luego el subdirectorio se lo pones al siguiente método, por ejemplo `move()`. `Storage::disk('public')->move('image/'. $oldFileName.$extension, 'image/'.$newFileName.$extension);`.

Comment: A eso me refería, sí sé que no podría hacerlo directamente al disk ya que llama al nombre del array. Gracias!

Comment: Sí voy a guardar las fotos en diferentes directorios (Por años), podría agregar una variable para definir el directorio? así: `Storage::disk('image')->move($photo->year.'/'.$oldFileName.'.'.$extension, $newFileName.'.'.$extension);` y para verificar si existe: `( Storage::disk('image')->exists($photo->year.'/'.$newFileName.'.'.$extension) )`

Comment: Sí, puedes darle el nombre que quieras al directorio. ¿Lo probaste y no funciona?

Comment: Lo probé y no funciona, lo estoy publicando como pregunta nueva...Si puedes áchale un viztazo. Gracias!